# Azure Scheduler Job Times Out

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-sql-database

Some time ago I set up a mobile job with the Azure scheduler service to run a stored proc on my Azure SQL database periodically. In about April this got migrated to the new Azure Portal, and since then it hasn't run successfully.

The stored proc takes about 90s to run, and I suspect the job times out before completing. It didn't timeout prior to migration so I think I must have fixed it previously via connection string or something.

Here's the full script that I am running:

```
function runTasks() {    
   var sql = "exec [dbo].[runTasks]"; 
      console.log("Executing runTasks...");
      mssql.query(sql,{
         success: function(results){
         console.log("Finished the runTasks job.");
         },
          error: function(err) {
            console.log("error is: " + err);
         }
     });
 }
```

Is there any way I can increase the timeout on this call?

(I'm not even certain where the connection string used for this code resides now that it's been migrated to the new portal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the job I was running was a SQL job, I installed SQL Server Management Studio on an Azure VM I had handy and set up the task as a scheduled SQL Agent job. That got past the timeout issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/#_on-demand-jobs for more info about the Scheduler Jobs after migration.

Also, we recommend that you convert all on-demand jobs to [WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/) or [Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-overview/). Write new scheduler jobs as [WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/) or [Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-overview/).

Additionally, Mobile Apps will be unloaded if they are idle for some period of time even if your webjob scripts are running.

by default. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. Especially if you need to run continuous or a long time job or task, you should enable Always On. You can modify this setting in manage portal, refer to [Configure web apps in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/) for details.

Comment: Hi Gary. My current WebJob is run by the Scheduler service. It's working fine, except that it times out running the stored procedure. I've decided to ditch all this and take a completely different approach (e.g. hangfire.io)

Comment: You can try to configure the app settings `SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT` in Azure portal, to enlarge the Web App's request timeout setting.

Comment: I've just tried that out (and WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT as well) but they didn't make any difference. Is the problem with the webjob calling the web app timing out? Or is it with the Web App calling the Stored Procedure?